# How to remove scrollbars in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, web-development

How do I make all the code visible without scrolling horizontally, so that all my code floats vertically like in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's the "Word Wrap" option you're looking for. In the "View" menu make sure the "Word Wrap" option is ticked. Then the line will never extend past the edge of the screen.